# I'm just a beginner in Logic Pro X, How can I change window from the main window

Tags: logic-pro

So I messed things up in Logic Pro X but I am a beginner myself, and I was wondering to ask how can I replace the window from the bottom and change it to Piano Roll window without opening it separately (new Window) from `Window > Open Piano Roll`.

[image: Changing the bottom window to Piano Roll]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind! Found it,
Just exploring some things here, Now why

[image: Found it here]